# was gladly sent to Italy

Tags: meaning, adverbs, ambiguity

a. He was gladly sent to Italy.

Could one use that sentence is he was the one who was glad about his being sent to Italy.

As far as I know, the adverb refers to the doer of the action, but I don't think that is necessarily the case. I think (a) is ambiguous. We can't tell who was 'glad' unless we have the full context.

Am I correct?

Comment: Someone gladly sent him  to Italy.

Comment: The verb is in passive voice.

Comment: To me it means he was glad to be sent to Italy, though a literal reading of the sentence agrees with Sam.

Comment: It suggests to me that the people who sent him were glad to be rid of him!

Comment: It reminds me of the all-too-common way that certain UK newspapers write that someone 'sadly died'. How do they know?